# Angular.json styles "inject" is not a valid property

Tags: angular, angular-workspace-configuration

I'm trying to add some custom styles to `angular.json > "projects" > "app-name" > "architect" > "build" > "options" > "styles"` but when I add my style object, the `Property inject is not allowed.`

```
{
   "input": "src/assets/theme/client-a-style.css",
   "bundleName": "client-a",
   "inject": true
}
```

I'm using Angular v6.0.8

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "bundleName" is a parameter of the styles array, remove the styles and just keep "input" and "inject". Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

In versions < v11
you must use lazy:true

[image]

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19504

Regards